# Using file-loaders in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, esbuild

I have a [file loader](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#file) set up for `.png` files with esbuild.

And I have this in my `index.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

But the problem here is that my editor doesn't warn me on any non-existing imports.

```
import existing from "assets/existing.png" // no error
import not_existing from "assets/not_existing.png" // no error
```

It only errors out once I build them with esbuild.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

When using an asterisk / glob star (`*`) in the declared specifier `*.png`, it will pattern match all specifiers ending in `.png`. If you want to restrict the recognized import specifiers to certain file names, then you can declare only those specifiers, for example:

```ts
declare const _pngBase64: string;
declare module "assets/existing.png" { export default _pngBase64; }
declare module "assets/existing2.png" { export default _pngBase64; }
// etc.
```

Comment: Does this mean that we have to maintain a list of images manually in `index.d.ts` ?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227936/using-file-loaders-in-typescript/76228144?noredirect=1#comment134425994_76228144) @Kokodoko In order to have compile-time type safety for custom loader specifiers that can't be handled by the compiler, yes — they must be maintained somewhere (or, for example, generated by another script). Whether that kind of type safety matters in the first place is still in question: the build should fail if an import is not found — so I think this is more of a developer experience concern.

Comment: I suppose this is the state-of-the-art as of now. The webpack documentation also relies on the same trick: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets

What kind of changes would be necessary for this situation to improve? I tried to look through the GitHub repo, and I saw some proposals/PRs that _might_ improve this problem at least indirectly, but I'm not so sure.

Still new to TypeScript's ecosystem, so some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Another solution to prevent selecting files that don't exist might be to use the file path autocomplete in VS Code. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227936/using-file-loaders-in-typescript/76228144?noredirect=1#comment134430163_76228144) @whatthe For the reasons in [TypeScript's design goals (and non-goals)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals), I doubt this will ever be supported natively without finalization of something like [import attributes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes) and using syntax from that spec. Ref: [TS GitHub issues search query for `import specifier`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+import+specifier)